# MySql Join Tables With Sum Of A Column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables in total

1. **category** with columns *category_id* and *category_name*
2. **server** with columns *server_id*, *category_id*, *server_name* and *server_url*
3. **server_hit** with columns *id*, *server_id*, *hit_count*, *day_date*

> Here in the **server_hit** table, I am storing how many times a web
> server is being accessed daily. And in the *day_date* column I am
> stroing date in this format **YYYYMMDD** where YYYY is the four digit
> year number, MM is the two digit month number & DD is the two digit
> date number.
>
> While inserting data in the **server_hit** table, if no row has been
> created yet with same date then first it creates a row and then insert
> data in the table.

Now what I want is a list of all the servers from the **server** table with the following columns. If no row exists in the **server_hit** table, then *total_hit_count* should be set to 0 (zero).

1. *server_id* from **server** table
2. *server_name* from **server** table
3. *server_url* from **server** table
4. *category_id* from **server** table
5. *category_name* from **category** table with condition server.category_id = category.category_id
6. *total_hit_count* from the **server_hit** which is  the sum of all the *hit_count* column of a particular server id.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I get the list like I described above? I have tried with **GROUP BY** but I could not make it work.

Any words will be cordially accepted. Thanks in advance.

#### Edit: Here is my query that I have used so far

```
SELECT DISTINCT SERVER.*, category.category_name, IF(EXISTS(SELECT DISTINCT id FROM server_hit WHERE server_hit.server_id = SERVER.server_id), (SELECT SUM(hit_count) FROM server_hit WHERE server_hit.server_id = server.server_id GROUP BY server_id), 0) AS 'total_hit_count' FROM server, category, server_hit WHERE server.category_id = category.category_id GROUP BY server.server_id;
```

Comment: Can we see your best efforts so far - and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Hi, I have given my query in the question. Please check the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, I believe the following should work.

The key is to issue the `LEFT JOIN` so that even a server with no matching record in the `server_hit` table will still show in the final output, but with a 0 sum.

```sql
SELECT s.server_id, s.server_name, s.server_url, s.category_id, c.category_name, IFNULL(SUM(sh.hit_count), 0)
FROM server s
INNER JOIN category c ON s.category_id = c.category_id
LEFT JOIN server_hit sh ON s.server_id = sh.server_id
GROUP BY s.server_id, s.server_name, s.server_url, s.category_id, c.category_name
```

Add `IF EXISTS` to handle `NULL` issue

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT s.server_id, s.server_name, s.server_url, s.category_id, c.category_name, IF(EXISTS(SELECT id FROM server_hit WHERE sh.server_id = s.server_id), SUM(sh.hit_count), 0) as 'total_hit_count' 
FROM server s 
INNER JOIN category c ON s.category_id = c.category_id 
LEFT JOIN server_hit sh ON s.server_id = sh.server_id GROUP BY s.server_id, s.server_name, s.server_url, s.category_id, c.category_name
```

Comment: sh.hit_count is an unfortunate name for a column

Comment: I have added "DISTINCT" keyword and it gives me correct number of rows, otherwise it adds some extra rows. But the only problem remains with hit count. It gives the total number of hit_count when the row exists in the server_hit table, otherwise it gives NULL by default. Can you set it to 0 (zero) somehow?

Comment: I have added IFNULL to the select to force the null to 0.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT s.server_id, s.server_name, s.server_url, s.category_id, c.category_name, IF(EXISTS(SELECT id FROM server_hit WHERE sh.server_id = s.server_id), SUM(sh.hit_count), 0) as 'total_hit_count' FROM server s INNER JOIN category c ON s.category_id = c.category_id LEFT JOIN server_hit sh ON s.server_id = sh.server_id GROUP BY s.server_id, s.server_name, s.server_url, s.category_id, c.category_name

Comment: This is the working query. @keelerm Thanks :)

Comment: I would advise revisiting the updated query I provided. Embedding a select within your select clause is going to cause performance issues as your tables grow in size. I am also curious as to why you need the DISTINCT. Do you have duplicate records in your server table?